# No matching bean when testing but works perfectly on server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I'm working on a spring-mvc project built by someone else. Everything works fine when running with Tomcat on localhost using Eclipse. I have also committed some code and they have been deployed by the supervisor successfully.

However, when I run a JUnit test which is basically as follows:

```
package com.my.package.test;

...

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:*/applicationContext.xml")
public class DataSynchronizationTest {
    
    @Autowired
    SomeMapper someMapper;
    
    //some tests
}
```

I'm suddenly getting the error:

```
 ... org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.company.project.dao.SomeMapper] found for dependency: ...
```

This seems weird to me because that's exactly how `someMapper` is injected in the web application. For example, the following works just fine:

```
package com.my.package.controller;

...

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
@Scope("session")
public class FooController extends BaseController {

    @Autowired
    SomeMapper someMapper;

    //...
}
```

I think I'm loading `ApplicationContext` correctly in this JUnit test because if I remove that `@ContextConfiguration` line or change it to `@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/applicationContext.xml")` then I would get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

So if I'm using the same `ApplicationContext` (there is only one. I didn't create another one for testing), why does the injection works fine on server, but fails in JUnit test? Any help is appreciated.

## Edit:

As M. Deinum said in the comment, I do have a `ContextLoaderListener` and a `DispatcherServlet`, both of which are defined in `web.xml`. Here is the relevant part of `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

However, `someMapper` lives in the `applicationContext.xml` (which is loaded by `ContextLoaderListener`) and apparently has nothing to do with the `DispatcherServlet` part. Here is the part of `applicationContext.xml` that is responsible for loading `someMapper`:

```xml
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> 
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:com/company/project/dao/*.xml" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:MyBatis-Configuration.xml"/> 
</bean> 

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.company.project.dao" />  
</bean>
```

`SomeMapper.java` and `SomeMapper.xml` are located in `classpath:com/company/project/dao/`, of course.

Comment: Where is the SomeBean you expect an instance of to be injected?

Comment: Check this similar issue if of any help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593741/nosuchbeandefinitionexceptionno-qualifying-bean-of-type-found-for-dependency-wi

Comment: Are you **really** loading the same configuration (I doubt it). I suspect you both have a `ContextLoaderListener` **and** and `DispatcherServlet`. Both of which load a different XML file to create 2 seperate application contexts. You are only loading the `ContextLoaderListener` one and basically only half of your application. As a rule of thumb, the exceptions are usually right and the error is generally on the users side.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your helpful comment! However, I still can't figure it out. Please see my edited post.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thank you for the comment. The `SomeMapper` of which I would like an instance to injected is a mybatis mapper. Please see my edited post.

Comment: Make sure you don't have additional configuration for mappers in your `mvc-dispatcher-context.xml` and are really sure everything is in the one you are loading (I somehow doubt it). Also you have obfuscated things which make it hard to correlate things, as the package names don't match up (the one in your error is different from the one you are using in your `MapperScannerConfigurer`).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for pointing out the mismatch of package names, I've corrected it in another edit. Ok I'm going to check it again.

Comment: Also you might want to enable debug/trace logging for everything and check to see what is going on.